# gcloud SSH in same terminal window

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

I use `gcloud cloud-shell ssh` to connect to Google Cloud Shell. However, this spawns a new window, (PuTTY) which bothers me. Is there a way (some `--` flag / &c.) to use it from the same console window?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLI is just a wrapper for launching Putty (on Windows) with the correct command line options. The SSH functionality is not built into `gcloud`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of directly opening the SSH session with `gcloud beta compute ssh` you can set up a tunnel from a local port to the GCP instance and then use your preferred terminal to ssh over the tunnel.
You set up the tunnel with:

```
gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel --zone <zone> <name of instance> 22 --project <name of project> --local-host-port=localhost:4226
```

You open an SSH connection to `localhost:4226` as you would do to the instance with:

```
ssh <user>@localhost -p 4226 -i <identity file>
```

(EDIT: make sure to include the identity file for GCP access)

Comment: Great answer, works with Cygwin too. If anyone has issues with identity then run the normal gcloud command that launches putty with `--verbosity debug`. It will log your remote username and the location of the putty ssh identity file that you need for the `<user>` and `<identity file>` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Using `--command` flag, you can run the command on the virtual machine without opening new console window.

```
gcloud compute ssh your-instance --zone=your-zone --command="ps aux"
```

It runs the command on the target instance and then exits.

Use `gcloud compute ssh --help` command to learn more.